# is there a good PHP CRUD code generator?

Tags: php, database, crud

Is there any better PHP CRUD code generator?
I want to get Data Access Object, Business Object and Value Object.
It would be difficult to match my needs, but I am happy at least I can get any relevant one.

[EDIT]

I am working on an MVC based application.
 I am using my own MVC framework.
 I need this code generator to generate codes for MODEL part.
 For example Entity Class and Value Objects Currently my codes are like below.

```
class CustomersDAO
{
   public function add() {$CustomersVO}
   public function update($CustomersVO) {}
   public function delete() {}
   public function get() {}
}
class CustomersVO
{
   public $id;
   public $name;
   public $tp;
   public $address;
}
class CustomerBO
{
   private $id;
   private $name;
   private $tp;
   private $address;

   public function getID() {};
   public function setID($val) {};
   // other getters and setters gos here..

   // other business logics
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP frameworks for simplifying CRUD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29126/php-frameworks-for-simplifying-crud) and a [couple others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PHP+Crud)

Comment: What I need is not a framework. I want to make my development easy for Data Access Layer

Comment: Check [PHPRunner](http://xlinesoft.com/phprunner). There is also [Grocery CRUD](http://www.grocerycrud.com/) worth trying.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

http://www.cakephp.org (scaffholding)

http://www.symfony-project.org

http://www.phpscaffold.com

http://www.scriptcase.net

all can generate the basic business logic via command line.

Comment: I checked phpscaffold.com. It is generating a full application with all functionality. I dont want that. I want some think like Entity classes and Value Objects. My application is based on MVC. I am using my own MVC framework. I know a code generator to make my work fast.

Comment: It looks like you're in need of a ORM rather than a framework? http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm

Comment: Yes I do not need a framework. I need the Model for integrating in to my existing View and Controller.

Comment: phpscaffold did the trick for me.  UPVOTED! :)

Answer (score 2):

You may have a look at

[Cygnite Framework](http://www.cygniteframework.com)

Does basic code generation.  Controller, model, views, layout, pagination, form component, required field validation etc.  all these generate with simple command. You may alter the 
code based on your need.

Here is the tutorial- [Generate CRUD application within 2 Min](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKuKUvalQHE)

Worth looking.

Answer (score 2):

[LaraAdmin](http://laraadmin.com) could be the best CRUD Generator and Admin Panel for Laravel. Its also generates Eloquent Models and Spectacular Views.

Answer (score 0):

You can find yet another PHP DAO generator/scaffolder - this one does not require manual configuration or table/columns settigs - it will read database schema structure from MySQL's INFORMATION_SCHEMA and automatically create ORM classes for selected tables with properties, CRUD(S) and finder functions, including getters for related objects.

http://phpdao.ir.com.hr